# Recognise language from the image

Tags: characters

Can someone help me by identifying ehat language it is?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chinese. 
translation: I think this is important to me and all the Latvian people.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any possibility to understand what region is it coming from or it's just basic Chinese?

Comment: no problem, and it's Basic mandarin. @mrserge